# Voice Chat, Increased Delay(Buffer) - Can it be solved?

Tags: c#, buffer, naudio

Okay so i am making a Voice chat software.
I am using NAudio for it, an excellent library.

But i got a problem. The buffer can go up when something happens. I guess it´s from example, when the OS loads something and the Voice Chat application is put on "hold" for a sec. During that time, it adds the data in the buffer, making the current data get delayed.

And as the receiver is playing at the same pace all the time, it will always be delayed.

Now i have a "solution" for this, which is to clear the buffer when it reaches a certain length. Though this is not ideal at all, and is more of a trick than a solution.

Now to the code parts.
First i initialize the things i use.

```
        private NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent SendStream = new WaveInEvent();
        private NAudio.Wave.AsioOut Aut;
        private NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat waveformat = new WaveFormat(48000, 16, 2);
        private WasapiLoopbackCapture Waloop = new WasapiLoopbackCapture();
        private NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider waveProvider;

  waveProvider = new NAudio.Wave.BufferedWaveProvider(waveformat);
                waveProvider.DiscardOnBufferOverflow = true; 
                SendStream.WaveFormat = waveformat;
```

waveformat is used just so i don´t have to rewrite it all the time.
DiscardOnBufferOverflow is used so if i set a certain lenght on the buffer, for example 20ms. It will Discard anything above, else it will return an exception. I think however it doesn´t do anything if i don´t set a length, it´s probably infinite at default.

And not much else, SendStream is a WaveInEvent, meaning it will run on a BackgroundThread when i use DataAvailable.  Waloop is pretty much the same except it´s a loopback.
waveprovider is used in the receiving part to play back the audio.
Waveformat is, well waveformat, it´s importat to set it out, and have all the same, at least in my application.

Here is the receiving part. As you can se, it puts the data in a byte array, then plays it. nothing weird.

```
   byte[] byteData = udpClient.Receive(ref remoteEP);
   waveProvider.AddSamples(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
```

Here is the sending/recording part.

```
  private void Sendv2()
    {
        try
        {
            if (connect == true)
            {
                if (AudioDevice == "Wasapi Loopback")
                {
                    SendStream.StopRecording();
                    Waloop.StartRecording();
                }
                else
                {
                    Waloop.StopRecording();
                    SendStream.StartRecording();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }

void Sending(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
       {
           if (connect == true && MuteMic.Checked == false)
           {
               udpClient.Send(e.Buffer, e.BytesRecorded, otherPartyIP.Address.ToString(), 1500);
           }

       }
void SendWaloop(object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs e)
   {

           byte[] newArray16Bit = new byte[e.BytesRecorded / 2];
           short two;
           float value;
           for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < e.BytesRecorded; i += 4, j += 2)
           {
               value = (BitConverter.ToSingle(e.Buffer, i));
               two = (short)(value * short.MaxValue);

               newArray16Bit[j] = (byte)(two & 0xFF);
               newArray16Bit[j + 1] = (byte)((two >> 8) & 0xFF);
           }
           if (connect == true && MuteMic.Checked == false)
           {
               udpClient.Send(newArray16Bit, newArray16Bit.Length, otherPartyIP.Address.ToString(), 1500);
           }

       }
```

Waloop is a Loopback, so it goes through another "channel", but it´s not really important here.

Very simple, When data is available (when it´s recording) and if the connect is true etc, it will just send the buffer.

So pretty much like the receiver part but other way around.

Now how i currently solve this is like this:

```
 if (waveProvider.BufferedDuration.Milliseconds > 40)
            {

                waveProvider.ClearBuffer();
                TimesBufferClear++;
            }
```

So i am clearing the buffer if it´s above 40ms (this is in a Timer at 600ms interval).
(TimesBufferClear++; is just so i can keep track of the times it had been cleared)

Now sadly, i have no idea how to prevent the buffer to be increased, and setting it to a forced state (20ms etc) will just cause the playback to be worse and worse the higher up the buffer goes as it doesn´t really stop, it just ignores the part above i think.

Here is the creationg of the input devices. It is a bit different from ASIO and Wasapi in my implementation, but it pretty much works the same, only real difference is that i tell the UI that ASIO is on or off as you can see in the code, at the end i add the DataAvailable event´s to both SendStream (any input, Microphone etc) and Waloop (Loopback sound that´s being played).

```
  private void CheckAsio()
    {

        if (NAudio.Wave.AsioOut.isSupported())
        {

            Aut = new NAudio.Wave.AsioOut();
            ASIO.Text += "\nSupported: " + Aut.DriverName;
            ASIO.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            Aut.Init(waveProvider);
            Aut.Play();
            SendStream.NumberOfBuffers = 2;
            SendStream.BufferMilliseconds = 10;
        }
        else 
        {
            AsioSettings.Enabled = false;
            ASIO.Text += "\n Not Supported: Wasapi used";
            ASIO.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray;
            Wasout = new WasapiOut(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 0);
            Wasout.Init(waveProvider);
            Wasout.Play();
            SendStream.NumberOfBuffers = 2;
            SendStream.BufferMilliseconds = 9;
        }
        SendStream.DataAvailable += Sending;
        Waloop.DataAvailable += SendWaloop;

    }
```

I am not sure if this even can be solved. But as i don´t see other voice chat programs have it, i am guessing there must be something that can be done.

Answer (score 1):

The way this appears to be handled in most applications is to send blocks of data a defined rate (in samples/sec), and drop blocks of data that exceed that rate.  If the sender is resource-limited and is not able to maintain the rate, the stream will have audio gaps.  This used to happen in audio calls over dial-up when the transmission rate was locked higher than the network connection could handle, or when the CODEC code was taking up too much time.

But from the sound of things the buffering and skips are symptoms, not causes.  The root of the problem is that your process is getting shelved for other operations.  You can address this by running at a higher process and/or thread priority.  The higher your priority the less interruptions you'll have, which will reduce the likelihood of data queuing up to be processed.

In .NET you can raise your process and/or thread priority fairly simply.  For process priority:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

...

Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = PriorityClass.Highest;
```

Or for a thread:

```
using System.Threading;

...

Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
```

This is not a complete solution, since the OS will still steal time-slices from your application under various circumstances, but in a multi-CPU/core system with plenty of memory you should get a fairly good shot at a stable recording environment.

Of course there are no fool-proof methods, and there's always that one slow computer that will mess you up, so you should allow the system to drop excess samples when necessary.  Keep track of how much data you're sending out and when it starts to back up, drop anything over your maximum samples/sec.  That way your server (or client) isn't going to be buffering increasing amounts of data and lagging further and further behind real-time.

One option there is to time-stamp each packet you send so that the client can choose when to start dropping data to catch up.  Better to lose a few milliseconds of output here and there than to drift further and further out of sync.

Comment: Sadly, i already have that, and usually runt my threads in highest priority. And it doesn´t change a thing:S it seems to be something else, cause it adds up no matter what. Pretty complicated and hard to track.

Comment: Odd.  Even a low-end system should handle this sort of thing without problems.  Is it a network issue?  Have you profiled to see how much time your code is taking to do each phase?  Have you tried separating the recording code into a different thread from the network code?

Comment: Yes i have, though i think it´s fault is in the actual "Waveprovider", as if i record the data on the Client and Server (As a file) both will be the same, no glitches that may happen when i listen to the chat Live. Meaning the Waveprovider must be the cause of it somehow, as it can be at 10ms all the time, then it will "crack" and can become 80ms, not sure what happens, but the saved that is as fluid as always, and the saved data and the data in the Waveprovider should be identical;S